# Custom message fetched from API in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I want my app users to share an link using an UIACtivityViewController. The link is not static and I have to fetch it from an api. I want to fetch this link as soon as someone presses a icon in UIActivityViewController but how I am doing it now is not working. The completionhandler of the request is always excuted at the end of the method fetchShareURL(). Could someone tell me how to fix this?

```
    import UIKit

    class ShareItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {


        var objects : [AnyObject]?
        var shareURL : String?

        init(objects : [AnyObject]?){
            self.objects = objects
        }

        func fetchShareURL() -> Bool{
            //fetch share url from api

            let api = Api()
            let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
            let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)
            dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {

                api.export(self.groupObjList, receiptObjList: self.receiptObjList){ status, message, url in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.shareURL = url

                        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                    })
                }

            });

            let delayInSeconds = 30.0;
            let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, delayTime)

            if self.shareURL != nil{
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }

        }


        @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
            return ""
        }

        @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
            if fetchShareURL() == true{
                return "Download files: "+self.shareURL!

            } else {
                return nil
            }

        }

        func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: String?) -> String {
            return "title of share"
        }

        func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: String?, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
            //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data to be provided in a UIActivityView takes time to provide, use a [UIActivityItemProvider](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemProvider_Class/index.html). It is an NSOperation subclass and solves the whole problem in a completely coherent way. Indeed, this sort of situation is exactly what it is intended for. (And watch the WWDC 2015 video on advanced NSOperation, please.)

Comment: And never never never use semaphores like this. If something is asynchronous, let it be asynchronous.

Comment: I have to admit, though, that if it were me — and it never would be, because what you're trying to do is really risky — then when the user taps the share button to summon the activity view I'd provide some cover interface and try to do the download then, so that I don't even show the view if there are reachability or timeout issues. That way, if I _do_ show the activity view, I've got the data. I'd still use NSOperations, but in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to this for now. Later I'll use an NSOperation.

```
    api.export(self.objects){ status, message, url in
        if(status == true){
            if let url = url{
                alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true){
                    let sharingItems = ["Share url", url]
                    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [ShareItemSource(url: url)], applicationActivities: nil)
                    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard]
                    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activity, success, items, error) in
                        //Response
                    }

                }
            }
        } else {
            //handle fail
        }
    }
```